QRegularExpressionValidator does not seem to work with negativ lookahead
I have the following regex which works fine with online validators (https://regex101.com/r/d56Jmg/1). It is for validating floating point numbers which have a maximum number of 9 digits.
^[-+]?(?!0\d)(?!(?:[.,]?\d){10,})\d*[.,]?\d+

When I use it with QRegularExpressionValidator it always returns Intermediate state. Even for strings which have more than 9 digits.
Can anyone explain that behaviour and maybe even suggest a solution?
Here is an example code for c++
    QString regex = "^[-+]?(?!0\\d)(?!(?:[.,]?\\d){10,})\\d*[.,]?\\d+";
    auto regex_validator = new QRegularExpressionValidator(QRegularExpression(regex));
    QString test("0.123456789");
    QString test2("+0.1234567");
    int pos = 0;
    auto test_ok = regex_validator->validate(test, pos);
    auto test2_ok = regex_validator->validate(test2, pos);

Both test_ok and test2_ok are Intermediate. I need test_ok to be Invalid.

test2_ok is QValidator::Acceptable

I think the problem lies in the use of lookarounds, I think the engine ignores them and "thinks" there is still hope for the input you provide.

@WiktorStribiżew this is my guess too.
